# Value not assigned to byte

Tags: java, arrays, rabbitmq

I'm having issues about my code, but I can't seem to find it. My problem is that the value I save in an array, isn't saved in my object. Code is (please notice that @Override part is in run() method, and linked list definition is in top of class:

```
private LinkedList<Order> orders = new LinkedList<Order>();

            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String tag, Envelope env, AMQP.BasicProperties props, byte[] body)
                    throws IOException {
                byte[] tmp = new byte[5];
                tmp[0] = nextID;
                nextID++;
                channel.basicPublish("", "toClient", null, new byte[]{tmp[0]});
                for (int i = 1; i < tmp.length; i++)
                    tmp[i] = body[i-1];
                orders.add(new Order(tmp));
                processOrders(tmp);
```

My Order class is simple

```
private byte id;
/**
 * Byte containing the amount of cups of coffee. Amount is represented as a
 * number (Integer)
 */
private byte coffee;
/**
 * Byte indicating the amount of cafe Latté that has been ordered. Amount
 * is represented as a number (Integer)
 */
private byte cafeLatte;
/**
 * Byte indicating the amount of smoothies that has been ordered. Amount
 * is represented as a number (Integer)
 * 
 */
private byte smoothie;
/**
 * Byte indicating the amount of Ice coffee that has been ordered. Amount
 * is represented as a number (Integer)
 */
private byte iceCoffee;
/**
 * Boolean showing if hot drinks has been served or not.
 */
private boolean hotServed;
/**
 * Boolean showing if cold drinks has been served or not.
 */
private boolean coldServed;

public Order(byte[] orders) {
    id = orders[0];
    coffee = orders[1];
    cafeLatte = orders[2];
    smoothie = orders[3];
    iceCoffee = orders[4];
}

public byte getId() {
    return id;
}

public boolean coldServed() {
    return coldServed;
}

public void serveCold(boolean coldServed) {
    this.coldServed = coldServed;
}

public void serveHot(boolean served) {
    hotServed = served;
}

public boolean hotServed() {
    return hotServed;
}

/**
 * Method for converting the order into a byte array.
 * @return a 5 columns byte array containing id, coffee, cafe latté,
 * smooties, ice coffees.
 */
public byte[] toByteArray() {
    return new byte[] {id, coffee, cafeLatte, smoothie, iceCoffee};
}

/**
 * Method for retrieving all the ordered cold drinks with id first.
 * @return An array with numbers indicating the amount of smoothies and
 * Ice coffee to make. Id of the order is first, smoothies next and last
 * Ice coffee.
 */
public byte[] getColdDrinks() {
    return new byte[] {id, smoothie, iceCoffee};
}

/**
 * Method for retrieving all the ordered hot drinks with id first.
 * @return An array with numbers indicating the amount of coffee and
 *  cafelatte to brew. Id of the order is first, coffee next and last
 *  cafeLatte.
 */
public byte[] getHotDrinks() {
    return new byte[] {id, coffee, cafeLatte};
}
```

When I run debugging in Eclipse, I see that the tmp array in handleDelivery method retrieves correct values from body array, and `orders.add(new Order(tmp));` adds an element to my linkedList, but only with values `id, 0,0,0,0` (note that id is the correct id recieved from rabbitmq), but if I for instance order a cup of coffee, the value 1 is lost when I call `orders.add(tmp));` somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects shouldn't be instanced by class (except constants), but by constructors or run methods. Changing from `private LinkedList<Order> orders = new LinkedList<Order>();` in class to `private LinkedList<Order> orders;` and added `orders = new LinkedList<Order>();` in `run()` solved the problem.

Comment: "Objects shouldn't be instanced by class, but by constructors or run methods." Where did you got this from? It is perfectly fine to instantiate objects on the class-level. Could you explain as to why moving the initialization to the `run`-method solves the problem?

Comment: No, I can't explain why, but as I solved the problem by making that change, I see that there's a difference, though I don't know what